# How confined should my unit tests be (Angular perspective)?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am currently writing unit tests for an Angular Controller that calls functions on a Service. I use jasmine spies to make sure that the call to the service passes in the correct parameters. Everything seems okay; this is more or less just testing the configuration of the Controller. I also test the returned value: the returned object contain certain properties and they are valid. Again, my confidence is high although the unit test has now entered into integration test area. I'm certain there are no bugs in this piece of functionality.

We refactored the service. It's function definition changed as well as the returned object. Tests all over the application are broken. To me, that almost seems okay. I *should* have lots of failing tests. A central point in my application no longer works. However, I'd also argue that changing an endpoint shouldn't be this big of a hassle.

So my question is: how should I test the call to the service? Am I doing too much by checking both the call and the response? IMO the response is all I should care about (as the parameters are implicitly being tested as well). Still, many tests seem to be failing for a simple change to an abstraction layer.

Comment: I disagree. If you're testing a controller in isolation, then the service should be mocked, and the only thing you should test regarding the service interaction is that the right parameters are being passed to the service. The response should be stubbed. If you test the actual response from the actual service code, you're not unit-testing the controller anymore.

Comment: I agree I'm not unit-testing the controller anymore but I could refactor all the failing unit tests of the **service** and I would now have mocks/stubs in my controller that don't accurately portray the real world. The controller's tests would all pass even though the controller itself is no longer working. I no longer have the confidence without running my e2e suite which takes a much longer time.

Comment: Well, you're supposed to refactor all the places where you stub the service, too.

Comment: But how would you know where all the refactoring needs to happen? You wouldn't have failing unit tests all over the place. Would you just need to be disciplined to go through every file and make sure the mock is updated if one exists? I understand this is a an API change and not just refactoring the implementation details so maybe that is necessary. But, to me, there seems to be smell there.

Comment: Well, that's a huge problem of dynamic languages such as JavaScript: refactoring is a pain. You can use TypeScript to reduce the problem. Otherwise, unless you have a really good IDE that refactors things magically even in JS, you can still search for the name of the service in all the unit tests.